# Haskell: Using MapReduce to search for substrings?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a simple program using an existing MapReduce implementation (the one in **Real World Haskell**).

As an example of using the framework, here is some code to count the number of words in a file:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Int (Int64)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import System.Environment (getArgs)

import LineChunks (chunkedReadWith)
import MapReduce (mapReduce, rdeepseq)

wordCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int
wordCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (length . LB.words)
                      rdeepseq sum

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  forM_ args $ \path -> do
    numWords <- chunkedReadWith wordCount path
    putStrLn $ "Words: " ++ show numWords
```

I need to use the same MapReduce framework to write a program that searches for some string (say "il"), and returns the line numbers where they were found. For example, the output may be:

```
verILy: found on lines 34, 67, 23
ILlinois: found on lines 1, 2, 56
vILla: found on lines 4, 5, 6
```

(The capitalization of "il" is not required.)

I'm a Haskell beginner and don't have any concrete ideas yet. I did notice that the Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 class has a member function `findIndices`. Is it possible to use this?

Any code or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would first try to solve it with just using lists http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html and then see if mapreduce can be used for this.

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to use MapReduce specifically, so it would be great if someone could help me with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's hit this one.

---

First we're going to need a way to find words in a string. That can be done using Regex, let's say the [`regex-tdfa`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa) package. The Haskell regex packages are nice but are VERY general and a little hard to read at first. We'll make a function that's just a wrapper over the matching operator `(=~)` mostly to make the type concrete.

```
wordHere :: LB.ByteString -> LB.ByteString -> Bool
wordHere word string = string =~ word
-- a.k.a.            = flip (=~)
```

---

Now, `mapReduce` breaks down a list like `([a] -> c)` by giving a lot of parallel, *local* "mapping" jobs of type `(a -> b)` to different sparks, then folding across all of the results in the reduce job as `([b] -> c)`. Generally there's no guarantee of *order* of the reduce step, but RWH's `mapReduce` actually does give us that guarantee.

RWH's `lineChunks` function, in effect, splits a document (LB.ByteString -> [LB.ByteString]) into chunks of a small number of lines. Our mapping jobs each get one of these chunks and needs to locally provide information about line matches. We can do that by splitting the chunks into their constituent lines, *locally* numbering the lines, mapping `wordHere` over them, and collecting the local line numbers where `wordHere` returned true. We'll do it generally first, replacing `wordHere` with any predicate `p :: (LB.ByteString -> Bool)`

```
import Control.Arrow

localLinesTrue :: (LB.ByteString -> Bool) -> [LB.ByteString] -> [Int]
localLinesTrue p ls = map fst . filter snd . map (second p) . zip [1..]
```

And now we can create local mappers like `localLinesTrue (wordHere $ LB.pack "foobar") . LB.lines :: LB.ByteString -> [Int]`.

Given mappers of that type also elucidates the types of the rest of the function a bit. We now have

```
>>> :t mapReduce rdeepseq (localLinesTrue (wordHere "foo")) rdeepseq
...    :: ([[Int]] -> c) -> [LB.ByteString] -> c
```

So our reducer must be of type `([[Int]] -> c)`. Cool, let's try to make that. If we have a list of list of `Int`s we can reconstruct the actual line numbers...

```
[[], [], [], [5], [3], [], []]
```

wait, actually, we can't. We need to add more information into our mapper—the number of lines that occur in each chunk. Fortunately, since we're carefully keeping our stuff disentangled, this is easy to add. We'd need a return type more like `([Int], Int)` where the second parameter is the linecount for that chunk. We can do that with "fanout" `(&&&)`.

```
mapper regex = (localLinesTrue (wordHere regex) &&& length) . LB.lines
```

and now our output will look like

```
[ ([], 3),  ([], 5),  ([3, 5], 10), ... ]
```

and we can implement a reducer which just counts using the `State` monad

```
reducerStep :: ([Int], Int) -> State Int [Int]
reducerStep (hits, count) = do pos <- get
                               modify (+count)
                               return (map (+pos) hits)

reducer :: [([Int], Int)] -> [Int]
reducer = concat . evalState 0 . mapM reducerStep
```

and we've got

```
mapReduce rdeepseq (mapper regex)
          rdeepseq reducer
  :: [LB.ByteString] -> [Int]
```

which ought to get you 95% of the way to the end.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the detailed answer. Unfortunately, it came a day after I needed the solution, but this is obviously not your fault. Marked as solved!